# Sql Server CE version installed on Windows Mobile 6 Rom

Tags: windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

Which is the version of SQL Server CE installed on Windows Mobile 6? I think is SQL Server 2005 Mobile Versión 3.0.

If I use a database of this version (3.0), will it work on version 3.1 and 3.5?

Thank you!

Comment: The version installed on Windows Mobile 6 is SQL Server CE 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a 3.1 database file with the 3.5 database engine it will need to be upgraded. If you attempt to open it in Visual Studio 2008 (which uses SQL CE 3.5) it will prompt you to do this. It can also be done programatically via the [SqlCeEngine.Upgrade method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.upgrade.aspx).

The best table I could find regarding which version you may expect to find in ROM is the [Device Capabilities and Required Development Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228843.aspx) document on MSDN, in particular the section headed "Database Technology Support" near the bottom.